# Cannot understand PHPMailer debug log

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to use PHPMailer, 
I have enabled opensll and it loads
I use XAMPP and PHPStorm

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP z88sm9679wrb.26 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO PhpStorm 2016.1.2
SERVER -> CLIENT: 501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "PhpStorm 2016.1.2" invalid, closing connection.501 5.5.4 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo z88sm9679wrb.26 - gsmtp
SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "PhpStorm 2016.1.2" invalid, closing connection.501 5.5.4 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo z88sm9679wrb.26 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO PhpStorm 2016.1.2
SERVER -> CLIENT: 
SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed: 
SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Here is my code

```
    <?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587; //ssl : 465 --- tls:587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "te.professionnel@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "*****";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('te.professionnel@gmail.com', 'Abou May');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('abou.may@gmail.com', 'Abou May');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}


 I have read lots of documentation, bu I cannot figure out the reason of this error.
```

Can someone givz me an example code?

What is wrong ?

I read all the section on troubleshooting

"SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."

This may also appear as SMTP connect() failed or Called Mail() without being connected in debug output. This is often reported as a PHPMailer problem, but it's almost always down to local DNS failure, firewall blocking (for example as GoDaddy does) or other issue on your local network. It means that PHPMailer is unable to contact the SMTP server you have specified in the Host property, but doesn't say exactly why. It can also be caused by not having the openssl extension loaded (See encryption notes below).

Comment: Smtp turned on in your google account?

Comment: I do not know if this is the cause, but in my case I had to log into my gmail account and change a setting there, something like "allow less secure login for remote apps .."  I do not recall exactly what they call that setting

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with gmail or oauth.

The problem is this line:

```
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO PhpStorm 2016.1.2
```

When PHPMailer's SMTP client says hello to a  server like this, by default it passes the name returned by the internal method `serverHostname()`. Normally this returns something like `localhost.localdomain`, or `mymac.local` (i.e. a real host name), but if that's not available, it tries to figure out what to use - and one of the things it falls back to is the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` super global, which in this case contains `PhpStorm 2016.1.2` (I'd guess because you're testing using PHPStorm's built-in web server?), which is not a valid host name, hence the error. This isn't a good move on PHPStorm's part and is probably worth reporting as a bug.

Fortunately you can override automatic determination of the client hostname using the `Helo` property, which exists precisely for occasions like this. Just do this:

```
$mail->Helo = 'my.host.name';
```

substituting either whatever your real host name is, or by calling some other function which gives a usable result.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem before.This is not the problem of PhpMailer.But in fact,this is cause by Gmail smtp is denied the connection,therefore you cant connect.
In order for you to solve this problem,you need to

**Configure an OAuth2 app** in [Google Developer Console](http://console.developers.google.com).
Step is [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2#configure-an-oauth2-app)

If you still cant manage to solve it,I recommend you to use [Postmark](https://postmarkapp.com/) as your mail server,it is a lot easier to set up the connection.

[Here](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-send-smtp.html) is the guide for the setup of Postmark.For me is a lot easier.Hope it helps.

Comment: This isn't the case. There are other problems that are solved by switching to OAuth, but this isn't one of them.